# Microsoft Lumia 540 refusing to download or upload whatsapp attachments

Tags: whatsapp, lumia-540

My Microsoft Lumia 540 is refusing to download WhatsApp attachments such as pictures, audio, documents, etc... over mobile data but data settings are in place and texts are received.

Comment: Please clarify the problem. How is it refusing? Do you get an error message or something? What have you tried?

Comment: Also, does your data connection work with other apps?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following two suggestions.

### Suggestion 1:

1. Open the person's profile where you cannnot download attachments.
2. Make sure *save incoming media* setting is **not set to never**.

---

### Suggestion 2

Only try this if you are refering to auto download.

1. Open WHatsapp.
2. Press the pivot (three ... at the bottom of the screen).
3. Go to Settings.
4. Go to *Chats and Calls* -> *media auto-download*.
5. Set it to download on mobile data.